# Elastisearch update by query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using this code in python for updating my docs in elasticsearch. It's working fine but it's difficult to use it for a millions docs because I have  to initialise the `id` value everytime to update every document.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, exceptions

elasticsearch = Elasticsearch()

elasticsearch.update(index='testindex', doc_type='AAA',   id='AVpwMmhnpIpyZkmdMQkT',
                 body={
                     'doc':{'Device': 'updated'}
                 }
                 )
```

I read in the Elasticsearch documentation that it's not yet included but:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_updating_documents.html

> Note that as of this writing, updates can only be performed on a
>   single document at a time. In the future, Elasticsearch might provide
>   the ability to update multiple documents given a query condition (like
>   an SQL UPDATE-WHERE statement).

Comment: I am pretty sure that `update_by_query` that gets as a parameter the q should work. Just check this for python http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update_by_query

Comment: Hello AhmyOhlin and welcome to the site. I edited your question to match the format of the other questions on this site, feel free to edit it again.

Comment: @christinabo
i want to change the value of Device from 'Boiler' to 'Test'.
i use the parameter q ='Device:"Boiler"' to update all docs with value 'boiler'  but i got the following error:
    TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'q'
this is my code
    `elasticsearch.update(index='testindex', doc_type='AAA', q    ='Device:"Boiler"',
                    body={
                         'doc':{'Device': 'TESTs'}
                     }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch Update by Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265578/elasticsearch-update-by-query)

Comment: @Blairg23: my Problem is to search all docs contains `Device:"Boiler"'` then update it 
my question is: how can  i use the q parameter in update
help op python says: 
q – Query in the Lucene query string syntax
i don't understand how i use it because there is no example.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using the `update_by_query` (not the `update`) and the `script`, you should be able to update the documents that match your query.

```
 q = {
     "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.Device='Test'",
        "lang": "painless"
     },
     "query": {
        "match": {
            "Device": "Boiler"
        }
     }
}

es.update_by_query(body=q, doc_type='AAA', index='testindex')
```

The above worked for me. The `q` finds the documents that match your query and the script updates the value using the `_source` of each document.

I hope it works for you too, possibly with some adjustment on the query you want to use.

Comment: i tried your code and it's working fine. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there a way to do this as an upsert?

Comment: I get this error using your sample code: elasticsearch.exceptions.ConflictError: ConflictError(409)

Comment: @Kourosh you need to pass conflict value, to avoid error. 
es.update_by_query(body=q, doc_type='AAA', index='testindex', conflicts='proceed')
This will ignore the conflict error.