# How delete fetched documents from elasticsearch with Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I m fetching some documents from elasticsearch with scroll api. I'm using python for this operation. I want to ask how to delete that fetched documents from elasticsearch in python? Can someone give an example of this.
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [Delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) and you can easily convert this to python code and refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42507008/4039431) SO answer for some python syntax.

Comment: Didn't you mean"delete by query" instead of "update by query"?