# Bulk Update for elasticsearch documents using Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch documents like below where I need to rectify **age** value based on **creationtime** **currentdate**

***age = creationtime - currentdate***

:

```
hits = [
   {
      "_id":"CrRvuvcC_uqfwo-WSwLi",
      "creationtime":"2018-05-20T20:57:02",
      "currentdate":"2021-02-05 00:00:00",
      "age":"60 months"
   },
   {
      "_id":"CrRvuvcC_uqfwo-WSwLi",
      "creationtime":"2013-07-20T20:57:02",
      "currentdate":"2021-02-05 00:00:00",
      "age":"60 months"
   },
   {
      "_id":"CrRvuvcC_uqfwo-WSwLi",
      "creationtime":"2014-08-20T20:57:02",
      "currentdate":"2021-02-05 00:00:00",
      "age":"60 months"
   },
   {
      "_id":"CrRvuvcC_uqfwo-WSwLi",
      "creationtime":"2015-09-20T20:57:02",
      "currentdate":"2021-02-05 00:00:00",
      "age":"60 months"
   }
]
```

I want to do bulk update based on each document ID, but the problem is I need to correct 6 months of data & per data size (doc count of Index) is almost **535329**, I want to efficiently do bulk update on **age** based on **_id** for each day on all documents using python.

Is there a way to do this, without looping through, all examples I came across using Pandas dataframes for update is based on a known value. But here **_id** I will get as and when the code runs.

The logic I had written was to fetch all doc & store their **_id** & then for each **_id** update the **age** . But its not an efficient way if I want to update all documents in bulk for each day of 6 months.

Can anyone give me some ideas for this or point me in the right direction.

Comment: What exactly do you need the `_id` for? Do you do another lookup with that id to update the age? Or is the age rather based on the difference of the two timestamps?

Comment: @JoeSorocin _id I need so that by mistake I do not update some other document. Just to keep track of which doc I am updating or in case of failure, which document was last updated

Comment: That won't be a problem because the updates will be atomic. Can you explain a little more the logic behind the `age` calculation? Is is just the timestamp difference or does anything else come into play?

Comment: @JoeSorocin age is just a difference , so creationtime is what we are reading from the original data from the server & currentdate we are inserting as the the time when the document was inserted

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, fetching the IDs won't be necessary. You don't even need to fetch the documents themselves!

A single [`_update_by_query` call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) will be enough. You can use [`ChronoUnit`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-datetime.html#_datetime_difference_examples) to get the difference after you've parsed the dates:

```
POST your-index-name/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
      def created =  LocalDateTime.parse(ctx._source.creationtime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));

      def currentdate = LocalDateTime.parse(ctx._source.currentdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    
      def months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(created, currentdate);
      ctx._source._age = months + ' month' + (months > 1 ? 's' : '');
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

The official python client [has this method too](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update_by_query). Here's a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42507008/8160318).

Try running this update script on a small subset of your documents before letting in out on your whole index by adding a query other than the `match_all` I put there.

---

It's worth mentioning that unless you search on this `age` field, it doesn't need to be stored in your index because it can be calculated at query time.

You see, if your index mapping's dates are properly defined like so:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "creationtime": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "currentdate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

the `age` can be calculated as a [script field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#script-fields):

```
POST ttimes/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "age_calculated": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(
                          doc['creationtime'].value,
                          doc['currentdate'].value );
          return months + ' month' + (months > 1 ? 's' : '');
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The only caveat is, the value won't be inside of the `_source` but rather inside of its own group called `fields` (which implies that more script fields are possible at once!).

```
"hits" : [
  {
    ...
    "_id" : "FFfPuncBly0XYOUcdIs5",
    "fields" : {
      "age_calculated" : [ "32 months" ]   <--
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: I am facing a weird issue. It seems to be with my mapping. This is my mapping in ES : ```{
   "currentdate":{
      "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm"
   },
   "creationdatetime":{
      "type":"date",
      "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm"
   }
}``` . I get this error while inserting to ES : ```u'failed to parse date field [2019-12-24T15:34:52] with format [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm]```.

Comment: This is how I am formatting it : 
```df_final['creationdatetime'] = pd.to_datetime((df_final['creationtime'].astype(str).str[:10]).astype(int), unit='s')
df_final['creationdatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_final['creationdatetime'], format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')```

Comment: However when I print the final dataframe in a .csv file, the output is correct : ```currentdate, creationtime, creationdatetime
2021-02-02 00:00:00, 1587132656820, 2020-04-17 14:10:56
2021-02-02 00:00:00, 1587243135874, 2020-04-18 20:52:15 ```

Comment: You're missing the `'T'` separator in your format from the first comment. Try this: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm`.

Comment: My doubt is why I need to specify ***"T"*** in format of ***creationdatetime***

Comment: The docs from your example seem to include it.

Comment: is there a way to avoid it, I see in your mapping also you have included "T" for creationtime but not for currentdate. In that case will I be able to be do normal date subtraction ?

Comment: I didn't see the `'T'` in `currentdate` so I left it out. TBH it confused me too.

Comment: I changed my mapping with "T"  in format , data got inserted successfully, when I try to update using above method, I get below error ```"cause": {
        "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason": "[vuDBv3cB_uqfwo-WAWct]: version conflict, required seqNo [45001], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [220001] and primary term [1]",
        "index_uuid": "jl6-JnfkSAOMAPie9wUXnA",
        "shard": "0",
        "index": "dummy"
      },
      "status": 409```

Comment: ```{
  "query": {"bool": {"should": [{"range": {"currentdate": {"gte": "2021-02-01 00:00:00","lt": "2021-02-03 00:00:00"}}}]}},
  "script": {
    "source": """
      def created =  LocalDateTime.parse(ctx._source.creationdatetime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
      def currentdate = LocalDateTime.parse(ctx._source.recorddate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));   
      def months = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(created, currentdate);
      ctx._source.age = months + ' month' + (months > 1 ? 's' : '');
    """,
    "lang": "painless"}
}```

Comment: Retry your request with a `?retry_on_conflict=3` parameter. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040923/8160318).

Comment: I am using ES 7.2, still I get ```"reason": "request [/dummy*/_update_by_query] contains unrecognized parameter: [retry_on_conflict]"```. I can see in official doc, ***retry_on_conflict*** is there

Comment: If I use ```POST <INDEXNAME>/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed```. I get ```"error": "Gateway Time-out",```

Comment: Sorry, use `retry_on_conflict` instead. If it times out, I think it's "fine" because it'll start a background process which you can monitor with `GET /_tasks` ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html)).